# Unable to insert data using with Database First and Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

i am working on mvc 4 with entity framework, 
   1)add the connection web.config
   2)Add the table using Ado.net entity template,
    3)Generate the code using Auto Code genetrated item because i would working on dbcontext,

I can retrive the data form database using below code

```
public ActionResult Details()
    {
        var dataContext = new DataContexts();
        var Candidate = (from m in dataContext.Candidates select m).ToList();
        return View(Candidate);

    }
```

I am unable to insert data using below code

```
     public ActionResult Create(Candidate Candidated)
    {

            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                using (var dataContext = new DataContexts())
                {
                    Candidated.CandidateId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    dataContext.Candidates.Add(Candidated);

                    dataContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(Candidated);
            }



    }
```

Where is the mistake? could any one help me

Comment: What is the error you receive? Are you sure the database is not trying to automatically assign a unique identifier to your `Candidated` entity?

Comment: nothing all click submit,just render the page,no data inserting

Answer (score 0):

what is your Datatype for CandidateID ?

If the Datatype is varchar the code will work fine for creating the NewGuid.